# Does testosterone weaken the immune system?

Tags: endocrinology, immune-system

I was reading this articles [here](https://www.inverse.com/article/32840-men-weaker-sex-evolutionary-biology) that states that the higher the blood level of testosterone is, the weaker the immune system gets.

I read another article about testosterone [here](https://www.healthline.com/health/benefits-testosterone) that focuses on the positive side of high testosterone blood levels and avoids the effects on the immune system.

So my questions is: **Does testosterone really weaken the immune system?**

Comment: this may help http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008874915000313?via%3Dihub